# Как разбираться в исходном коде stl?

Tags: stl, c++

Многие моменты непонятны, к примеру этот :

```
#define _IOSskipws      0x0001
#define _IOSunitbuf 0x0002
enum _Fmtflags
        {   // constants for formatting options
        _Fmtmask = 0xffff, _Fmtzero = 0};

    static const _Fmtflags skipws = (_Fmtflags)_IOSskipws;
    static const _Fmtflags unitbuf = (_Fmtflags)_IOSunitbuf;
```

Это части кода из файла xiobase. Зачем _IOSunitbuf приводится к _Fmtflags и как работает это приведение?
В общем это один из вопросов. Может есть где-нибудь статьи/книги/..., которые бы если не полностью, то частично объясняли код в исходниках? Вероятней всего, что опытные программисты поймут почти весь код и при первом знакомстве с STL, потому как вряд ли там своя экосистема и они уже встречали подобные коды в разных источниках. Возможно когда-нибудь и я смогу делать это с простотой, но сейчас хотелось бы какой то документации(по исходному коду, а не по тому что он дает) для чайников что-ли).

Comment: Не стоит копаться в исходниках, вам придётся выучить кучу ненужных подробностей конкретной имплементации.

Для работы с STL достаточно формального описания. Я бы посоветовал вот это: <http://en.cppreference.com/w/>, если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте здесь или на stackoverflow.

Comment: @VladD как там в старых анекдотах?

    -- Запомните дэти, ибо понят это нэвозможно: ТАРЕЛЬКА пишэтся без мягкого знака, а КОН -- с мягким.
     Потом на уроке химии:
     -- Учител, пачэму ты написал КОН без мягкого знака?
     -- Это щелочь, идиот!

Comment: @avp, Спасибо! Конвертируете свои последние 3 комментария в ответ.

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Меня тоже всегда интересовало, почему код STL так безобразно оформлен. Я бы даже сказал, обфусцирован.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[[[[@strol](/users/14769/strol)](/users/14769/strol)](/users/14769/strol)](/users/14769/strol), по сути этот код сводится к 4-м макросам

```
#define _IOSskipws  1
#define _IOSunitbuf 2
#define  skipws     _IOSskipws
#define  unitbuf    _IOSunitbuf
```

все остальные буковки неужны для того, чтобы компилятор вдоволь поругался на *возможные* ошибки программиста в разных частях кода.

Обычно это называют заботой о качестве программного обеспечения (или чем-то в этом духе) и пишут на эту тему целые книги.

Вы спросите: Почему 4, а не 2 макроса?

Скорее всего это связано с некой несогласованностью при проектировании (короче, просто исторически так сложилось...)

Но сразу напишу, что реально большой плюс enum _Fmtflags заключается не только в том, что компилятор проверяет типы, но и отладчик "видит" эти имена (в отличие от имен в #define).

Тоже - так сложилось. Лично я предпочел бы улучшить отладчик (хотя, конечно, одно другому не мешает).

--

А это уже ответ на комментарий

```
Ясно). А стоит ли в каких-то других исходниках больших библиотек копаться? К примеру в некоторых частях буста. Или там не лучше с читабельностью?
```

[[[[@strol](/users/14769/strol)](/users/14769/strol)](/users/14769/strol)](/users/14769/strol), думаю не лучше. Это не означает, что в STL плохо.

Дело тут в том, что:

1. такой код не преследует образовательные цели
2. предполагается хорошее знание предмета (т.е. что в какой ситуации делает функция, а вовсе не познание функциональности путем чтения кода)
3. обычно код мультиплатформенен (это его часто либо засоряет, либо заставляет разработчика делать достаточно абстрактную структуру, где реализация конкретной функциональности лежит внизу, да и связи по данным не всегда очевидны)
4. желающие могут дополнять до бесконечности...

--

Но, все равно **читайте чужой код** (особенно известных библиотек).